# What is the correct way to populate the validation faild file input field of the form with original value so that it could be displayed in JSP file?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, web

The submited `csvUploadForm` which contains a file input field has been populated successfully and the `csvValidator` works fine.

I want to display the original content with error message in the JSP file so as to acknowledge the validation failed file input field.

The strange thing is that `form:errors path="feedItem"` works just fine while   `form:input path="feedItem"` has value but does not show up.

What is the problem?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView csvUploadCheck(@ModelAttribute("csvUploadBean") CSVUploadBean csvUploadForm,
        BindingResult bindingResult)
        throws Exception {
    csvValidator.validate(csvUploadForm, bindingResult);
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = this.initFormModelAndView();
        List<String> errors = buildErrorMessages(bindingResult);
        modelAndView.addObject(CSV_MODEL_ATTRIBUTE, csvUploadForm);
        modelAndView.addObject("errors", errors);
        return modelAndView;
    } else {
        final ContentModelAndView redirectModelView = new ContentModelAndView();
        redirectModelView.setViewName("redirect:foo");
        return redirectModelView;
    }
}



<form:form  method="POST" modelAttribute="csvUploadBean" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <a:section id="mylayout-middle">
        <c:forEach items="${errors}" var="error">
            <a:alert alertType="${'error'}" spacing="${'base'}">
                "${error}"
              </a:alert>
        </c:forEach>

        <form:input path="feedItem" name="feedItem" type="file" />
        <form:errors path="feedItem" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;"
```

Html source on the page:

```
<input type="file" value="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile@6b749731" name="feedItem" id="feedItem">
```

Html page behaviour:

```
No file select
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are destroying the state yourself, you are doing things way to complex.

Just construct a `ModelAndView` based on the `BindingResult` which is/contains the model.

```
if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = this.initFormModelAndView();
    List<String> errors = buildErrorMessages(bindingResult);
    modelAndView.addObject(CSV_MODEL_ATTRIBUTE, csvUploadForm);
    modelAndView.addObject("errors", errors);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Instead of this work with the framework as that already does al that for you.

```
if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = ModelAndView("your-view", bindigResult.getModel());
    return modelAndView;
}
```

That is all you need. If you need to make it more complex you ar probably doing things the wrong way. When having the proper annotations and config on your controller you could even make it simpler, by only returning the name of the view.

```
if (bindingResult.hasErrors() ) {
    return "your-view";
} else {
    return "redirect:foo";
}
```

Then add `@Validated` to your method argument that needs validation and use an `@InitBinder` method to set the validator you want to use for validation.

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(this.csvValidator);
}
```

Comment: Why even when I try to restore the state manually, it does not work as well ? `modelAndView.addObject(CSV_MODEL_ATTRIBUTE, csvUploadForm);`  and `modelAndView.addObject("bindingResult", bindingResult);`  Is there any to restore state manally? Because in my case I am afraid I have to restore the state munally.

Comment: Because that isn't restoring state that is only adding things, again work with the framework not around it.

Comment: The validation failed file input field can not be displayed correctly on the JSP page. Even it seems there is content in this validation failed file field `<input type="file" value="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile@6d410a79" name="feedItem" id="feedItem">` but it is empty on the JSP page.

Comment: I tried text field, it works. Is there any reason why type of input can not be restored?

Comment: Because there isn't really any content for that field... The browser keeps the location of the selected file(s) and on submit sends those files to the server. On the server there is no way to know the local file location on the clients machine.

Answer (score 0):

In your CsvValidator you might use *Errors.rejectValue(String field, String errorCode)* method to bind error to specific field.